# Do I need to parenthesise yield in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, yield, parentheses

In Ruby I can use

```
result << (yield element)
```

and everything works, but if I do

```
result.push(yield element)
```

I get a warning about needing parentheses for future compatibility. I can change the above to

```
result.push(yield(element))
```

and the interpreter is happy again, but I don't understand why I need parentheses in one call to yield and not the other?

Comment: The second example has a nested function call.
Ruby won't complain about non-nested calls (i.e. `puts "hello"` is fine) It's not specific to `yield`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore that warning. You won't get it anymore in 1.8.7 and later. The planned parser changes that were the reason for this warning, have been dismissed.